# How can I get something specific from json in node.js

Tags: node.js, json, youtube

I am trying to get a youtube subscriber count using googles node.js API https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client and I am also using the youtube data api from google https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/ I am trying to get subscriberCount from here https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=channel_id&key=api_key and here's what I have
here is my code and what I am getting https://hastebin.com/sotejijole.js, subscriberCount is in statistics: [Object] but I don't know how I can get to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really read some basic documentation regarding accessing properties inside JavaScript objects by name.

[Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

---

To answer your specific question: to access the subscriber count of the first search result, or, in your case, the only search result, you need to access the **subscriberCount** property of the first element inside the **items** array property like so:

```js
const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);

const subscriberCount = parsedResponse.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
```

---

Brief explanation: your parsed response object will generally contain information about more than one YouTube channel. I've made up two different channels and corresponding statistics and etags as example below.

The **items** property of the response object is an *array*, so information about the first and the most relevant search result will be contained inside the first element of the **items** array property. This first element of the **items** array has a **statistics** property which itself has a **subscriberCount** property.

```js
{
    kind: 'youtube#channelListResponse',
    etag: 'XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/JPcXxXpVfYrflWLNIZU24SubpLk',
    pageInfo: {
        totalResults: 1,
        resultsPerPage: 1
    },
    items: [
        // the first search result
        {
            kind: 'youtube#channel',
            etag: 'FiRsTXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/WibSoST9VFEdm73aOWaD9hhI1AM',
            id: '',
            statistics: {
                viewCount: 12877,
                commentCount: 43,
                subscriberCount: 133,
                hiddenSubscriberCount: false,
                videoCount: 26
            }
        },
        // the second search result
        {
            kind: 'youtube#channel',
            etag: 'SeCoNdPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/WibSoST9VFEdm73aOWaD9hhI1AM',
            id: '',
            statistics: {
                viewCount: 1334440,
                commentCount: 224,
                subscriberCount: 1122,
                hiddenSubscriberCount: false,
                videoCount: 114
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try doing this, also I apologise to others if my question wasn't clear. But thanks for answering and hopefully I can get this to work now :D